# UE4 - Can't connect Unreal Live link with iPhone X Live Link Face app?

Tags: ios, iphone, unreal-engine4, iphone-x

I try to connect the iPhone X app - Live Link Face with UE4 but I have a problem. I connect everything from the tutorial and from Epic docs but still have a problem. Live link subject name doesn't recognize my iPhone device. I put the IP address from my pc in-app but noting.

I'm using Windows 10, Face AR SAMPLE - default project from Epic Games - Learn category for Live Link Face app. [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was encountered the same problem in windows 10 until I changed my network profile from "Public" -> "Private" and then live link recognized my iPhone all in sudden!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just got it to work after trying for like 5 hours, haha

Here are some things that helped:

-Windows 10 turning Firewalls off
-Public connection --> Private
-the IP address on my phone was slightly different than the one on my computer, even though both were on the same Wifi connection. On my phone/Livelink app, I entered in the IP address of my computer.
-on my computer /Unreal, go into  Edit>Project Settings>UDP Messaging and then enter in the same IP address under "Unicast Endpoint" with :0 at the end
I also tried adding in :11111, i cant remember which worked haha

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I turned off the firewall on the private network
[image]

[image]